# Is there a more elegant way to query many to many tables on multiple ORs and ANDs?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables `dishes`, `ingredients` and `dishes_ingredients`. I would like to show all dishes that have `mango` and `chicken`. I can achieve this by first getting all dishes containing `mango` and then selecting all dishes that (also) contain `chicken` within these results. Like this:

```
SELECT e_dishes.id, e_dishes.name FROM 
(
 SELECT DISTINCT dishes.id, dishes.name FROM dishes 
 JOIN dishes_ingredients ON dishes.id = dishes_ingredients.dishes_id 
 JOIN ingredients ON dishes_ingredients.ingredients_id = ingredients.id 
 WHERE ingredients.name = 'mango'
) AS e_dishes
JOIN dishes_ingredients ON e_dishes.id = dishes_ingredients.dishes_id
JOIN ingredients ON dishes_ingredients.ingredients_id = ingredients.id
WHERE ingredients.name = 'chicken';
```

But it does not seem elegant enough. I think that there must be a way to get all dishes containing `mango` and `chicken` in just one query.

Comment: Another way, which is at least logically more elegant, would be to get all dishes containing _mango_ and then all dishes containing _chicken_ to then SELECT only those that repeat in both results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
SELECT  d.id, d.name
FROM dishes d JOIN
     dishes_ingredients di
     ON d.id = di.dishes_id JOIn
     ingredients i
     ON di.ingredients_id = i.id 
WHERE i.name IN ('mango', 'chicken')
GROUP BY d.id, d.name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;  -- number of ingredients
```

This assumes that the same ingredient is not listed twice.  If so, use `having count(distinct i.name) = 2`.

Note the use of table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.

Comment: Thanks, it does indeed look much more elegant but it does not do what I wanted. I get all dishes containing _mango_ AND all dishes containing _chicken_, not just those containing both ingredients.

Comment: @Pirula . . . Then you are doing something wrong.  This does an aggregation and the `having` clause requires that both ingredients be in the dish.

Comment: you are right, I was doing something wrong. It does work and it is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again.